# remove 'noindex' meta tag, under Tumblr

Tags: seo, tumblr

Is it possible to remove the meta tag for search engine 'noindex' in a tumblr blog ?
I have tried all options under the dashboard.
I think Tumblr add this option automatically when the HTML page is generated.
If I wrote another meta tag before, in a custom HTML style, is it used by googleBot or other ?

> < meta name="robots" content="noindex"/ >< meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off"/ >< /head >
>   < body >
>   ...

Also, these scripts are in the template :

```
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/xsp9wak/WsCkloo8h/fluid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/xsp9wak/trzklb43b/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/xsp9wak/6JXkli7dk/cufon-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/xsp9wak/g6Wklb4aa/tg.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> 

Comment: why you have removed the stackechange tag GoogleBot ?? This is this robot that read my meta tag ...

Answer (score 2):

Check: **Allow search engines to index your blog** in the blog settings.

Comment: checking this box have no effect on source code

Comment: Hum, other thumblr blogs don't have it. Are you sure the tag it's not on your editable html template?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Otherwise, I suspect the javascript file of the template, but I found nothing.

Comment: @boup FYI JavaScript has no effect on what you see in View Source.